# Poor image quality after added to PDF with itextsharp

Tags: c#, itext

I want to create a portrait gallery with some photos. In order to achieve this, I add everything I need in a panel and then I get the visual of this panel to add it in a PDF.

My problem is that I managed to create the PDF containing the image, but it is bad quality.

[Example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wc57w.png)

[Example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6lkAa.png)

We see that the outline of peoples is not clear, while in the original photos the outline is very clear.

```
iTextSharp.text.Document doc = new iTextSharp.text.Document();

panelTombi.AutoScrollPosition = new Point(0, 0);
panelTombi.AutoSize = true;
panelTombi.Refresh();
int width = panelTombi.Width;
int height = panelTombi.Height;

Bitmap MemoryImage = new Bitmap(width, height);

panelTombi.DrawToBitmap(MemoryImage, new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, width, height));

iTextSharp.text.Image image1 = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance((System.Drawing.Image)MemoryImage, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                       
image1.ScaleToFit(doc.PageSize);   
image1.SetAbsolutePosition(0, PageSize.A4.Height - image1.ScaledHeight - doc.TopMargin);
MemoryImage.Save(Path.GetDirectoryName(sfd.FileName) + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(sfd.FileName) + ".jpeg"); 
                        
//Save pdf file
PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(sfd.FileName, FileMode.Create));
doc.Open();
doc.Add(image1);
doc.Close();
```

As you can see, the image is also saved.

Could you tell me how to fix this image quality problem on the PDF file?

Thank you

Comment: _panelTombi.DrawToBitmap_ Most likely this reduces the resolution to the screen's resolution, which may be a good deal worse than the original images..

Comment: I tested this solution: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x-tMlZ3LTw8 but the problem was the same.

Comment: you used JPEG. Try bmp format. Just a wild guess.

Comment: Same problem. But as you can see in my first message, I save the PDF and the image. The image has always a good quality but some pixels are white: http://prntscr.com/1spq0vj

But the PDF has always the same problem no matter the image format, the outline of people is not sharp.

Comment: With itext7 it's better. I also found that the image is directly centered in the PDF and placed at the top of the page whereas with the old version I had to do a rough calculation and set the placement via a line of code.

Comment: What are the original dimensions of the image and what are the desired dimensions? Note: The desired dimensions must be <= the original dimensions.  You can find the original dimensions by hovering over the image with the mouse (or by opening the image in Paint-dimensions are at the bottom). Please post an original image that can be used for testing.

Comment: @user9938 problem fixed. But not one problem.

White pixels are not on the original photos and are not displayed in the software I created. The white pixels are only visible on the image resulting from saving everything displayed in the panel and only on the photo of certain people. So strange, because white pixels are not displayed in the PDF which displays the same as the picture.

If anyone has an idea I invite them to share their theory :)